# Lines with color ranges

Tags: php, css, magento

I have my code that builds a table with some data, and I want to differentiate the lines by color using CSS and PHP.

My code:

```
    foreach ($resultSql as $line) {


        $_atribute = $this->recoverAtribute($line'attribute_id']);

        $_optionText = $this->recoverOptionid($_atribute, $line['option_id']);
        $desc=$line['ds_cont'] ;
        $order   = array("\n");
        $replace = '<br />';
        $newstr = str_replace($order, $replace, $desc);   

        if($line['ds_cont']='dest'){
            echo $line['ds_cont']='';
        }
        if (isset($line['ds_cont']) && $line['ds_conteudo'] != '') {
            echo '<tr >    
            <td class="table-carac-title" style="padding-left: 45px !important;padding-right: 45px !important; "> ' .  ucwords( strtolower($_optionText)) . '</td>    
            <td class="table-carac-desc" style="padding-left: 45px !important;padding-right: 45px !important;"> ' . $newstr. '</td>
        </tr>';
        } else {
            echo '<tr >
            <td  class="table-carac-title" style="padding-left: 45px !important;padding-right: 45px !important;">' . $_atribute->getFrontend_label() . '</td>

            <td class="table-carac-desc" style="padding-left: 45px !important;padding-right: 45px !important;"> ' . $_optionText . '</td>
            </tr>';
        }  
        $count = $count + 1;    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a logic of odd and even numbers and add to the class of your  exemple:

```
        $classtest = '';

        if ($count % 2 == 0) {
            $classtest = 'pair';
        } else {
            $classtest = 'odd';
        }
```

and in yout TR tag :

```
'<tr class="active ' . $classtest . '">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set specific css on even and odd rows:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your $count variable to set what type color or other value you want change per line, like below:

```
if ( ($count % 2) == 0 )
    $myColor = "color:black";
else
    $myColor = "color:white";

# In you HTML element

echo sprintf('<tr style="%s"> ... something ... </tr>', $myColor);
```